# Convert a HTML element in JS to be created using createElement()

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to convert a part of code I built, in JS to use more clean solutions. 
I used to return HTML tags as follow:

```
return `<option value="${o.id}">${o.name}</option>`;
```

My goal is to use the create element or another way to write this differently to look cleaner.

this tag is a par of a map:

```
var selectOptions = response.map(o => {
                return `<option value="${o.id}">${o.name}</option>`;
            });
```

I would like to understand how to convert this doing like:

```
var x = document.createElement("option")
var value = "option value";
var text = "option.text"
And append
```

Or another way more useful in my example.

Comment: use `x.value = 'some value'; and x.innerText = 'some text'` and then append wherever you want

Comment: I tried that also but is not working as the values I have in ${o.id} and ${0.name} are not passed into my view. I got issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can crate an `Node` wrapper with  `document.createElement("div")` and attach the `template String` created with `node.innerHTML = template`;

```
const createNodeFromTemplate = (template, wrapper, wrapperAttrs) => {
  const node = document.createElement(wrapper);
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(wrapperAttrs)) {
    node.setAttribute(key, value);
  }
  node.innerHTML = template;
  return node;
};
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost I going to share the JSFiddle of what I'm doing maybe you can help me with that https://jsfiddle.net/jakub41/t3ejnuoh/ line is 126 I'm just lost how should do something like yours how into what I did